# Cast from datetime to date using hibernate and informix

Tags: java, hibernate, informix

I have a problem with the 'cast' expresion in Hibernate,
when I execute the next HQL:

```
SELECT new es.xunta.surex.vo.informes.ActividadUsuarioAuxVO(usu.codusu, cast(au.dataaudit as date), fun.idfunaudit, count(*)) 
FROM AuditAnotacion au, FunAuditoria fun, Usuario usu
WHERE au.funAuditoria.idfunaudit=fun.idfunaudit
AND  au.usuario.idusu=usu.idusu
AND  usu.unidade.iduni=:iduni
AND  au.dataaudit between :desde AND :hasta
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Hibernate 'translates' it into this SQL:

```
select
    usuario2_.codusu as col_0_0_,
    cast(auditanota0_.dataauditasdate) as col_1_0_,
    funauditor1_.idfunaudit as col_2_0_,
    count(*) as col_3_0_
from
    audit_anotacion auditanota0_,
    fun_auditoria funauditor1_,
    usuario usuario2_
where
    (
        auditanota0_.idfunaudit=funauditor1_.idfunaudit
    )
    AND(
        auditanota0_.idusu=usuario2_.idusu
    )
    AND(
        usuario2_.iduni=?
    )
    AND(
        auditanota0_.dataaudit between ? AND ?
    )
group by
    1 ,
    2 ,
    3
order by
    1 ,
    2 ,
    3
```

And I get this error:

```
A syntax error has occurred.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Because It's parsing the cast like this 'cast(auditanota0_.dataauditasdate)'
instead of 'cast(auditanota0_.dataaudit as date)'

I'm using org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect, so what's wrong?

Could you help me? Please.
Thank you.